# Missing overline and extra horizontal space when using unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\closure[1]{\overline{#1}}

\begin{document}

The intersection of the closed ball $\overline{B}(1)$ with the closed 
ball $\closure{B}(2)$ is the same as the intersection of the closed
ball $\closure{B}(2)$ with the closed ball $\overline{B}(1)$.

\end{document}
```

This is what I'm seeing (with `xelatex`):
[image]

Note the extra space before "B(2)" and the missing overline.

The problem goes away when I comment out `\usepackage{unicode-math}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `unicode-math` silently redefines `\closure` to yield the character

> ⁐ U+2050 CLOSE UP

which seems to be a “hidden feature”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand{\closure}{}%
  \renewcommand\closure[1]{\overline{#1}}% 
}

\begin{document}

The intersection of the closed ball $\overline{B}(1)$ with the closed
ball $\closure{B}(2)$ is the same as the intersection of the closed
ball $\closure{B}(2)$ with the closed ball $\overline{B}(1)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/486

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the quick response.